# Is it possible to use the Xserve VPN service without using the DHCP service?

Tags: vpn, xserve

I'm working on a friend's network and he's currently got a cisco router handling DHCP. Does the Xserve VPN service require that the Xserve also be handling DHCP?

Xserve 10.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Snow Leopard server VPN does not require that the XServe handles DHCP, though you'll likely want to have several IPs on the LAN that will be reserved for the connected device...

Comment: To clarify this slightly: the XServe doesn't need to handle DHCP, but it will handle the somewhat-DHCP-like function of handing out IP addresses to incoming VPN clients. You need to make sure that the ranges of IP addresses the Cisco DHCP server and XServe VPN service hand out don't overlap, or you'll have address conflicts between local and remote computers.

Comment: Thank you! I already reserved the IPs, and made sure the router's range excluded those same one.